# Why does read after right method not produce consistent results?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, cassandra, akka.net

I'm watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozelpjr9SXE) about Akka.net and the speaker says read after right does not produce consistent results because the order of events is not predictable at the network level. The arhcitecture the presenter is speaking about in this video is as follows:

1. One Load Balancer
2. Multiple web servers. Load balancer determines which server to hit.
3. One database server (SQL Server).

I'm confused to why consistent results are not achieved with a single databse? If a lock is put before data is written wouldn't that bring you back consistent results?

Comment: It would really help if you indicated what database you are talking about. 2 of those you have listed have transactional commits, one does not. Cassandra just uses LWW policy for writes and has no locking mechanism to ensure that a read waits for a write to complete before returning the read.

Comment: @RussS Good catch! I updated the answer with sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm going to guess you're talking about the scenario Aaron describes about 10 minutes into this video. Here's the scenario:

1. User is clicking things on a site and we're firing off asynchronous requests to record the clicks.
2. The not obvious part from the scenario he's describing is that *we're not waiting for the previous requests to finish* before sending more requests to capture a user's clicks (imagine a single page app where clicks don't cause a full refresh of the page from the server). We want to capture all the clicks.
3. We have some logic on the server that says, "If the user clicks these 3 things in a row, do some cool reaction..."
4. We check our condition on the web server ("Has the user clicked these 3 things in a row?") by writing the click event we just got to our DB, then reading to see if they've generated the stream of 3 things clicked to do our cool reaction.

Here's the problem: each request to record a click could be going to a different web server and we're not waiting on the previous one to finish before we send more requests to record clicks. So we have no guarantee that the request to write the first event has completed before we write the second, or the third, etc.

For example, the first request could be delayed (or even fail!) because of a faulty network, so the second request could reach our SQL Server first! And such, when it goes to read the stream of events that's happened, it could not be aware that a request was sent (but hasn't completed) to record that the first event happened.

I think the point he's trying to make is that in the face of multiple clients (in this example, web servers) writing to a database concurrently, you can't count on, "I sent that first so it will be recorded first". This holds true whether you're using DataStax Enterprise, Cassandra, SQL Server, Oracle, or whatever. Hope that helps!